# GetRequestStream method and hanging thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, httprequest, httpresponse

Assume I have the following code:

```
private string PostData(string functionName, string parsedContent)
    {
        string url = // some url;
        
        var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));

        http.Accept = "application/json";
        http.ContentType = "application/json";
        http.Method = "POST";
        http.Timeout = 15000; // 15 seconds

        Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parsedContent);

        using (Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream())
        {
            newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = http.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return content;
            }
        }
    }
```

I set up a breakpoint over this line of code:

```
using (Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream())
```

before `http.GetRequestStream()` gets executed. Here is a screenshot of my active threads:

[image]

This whole method is running in background thread with `ThreadId = 3` as you can see.

After pressing F10 we get `http.GetRequestStream()` method executed. And here is an updated screenshot of active threads:

[image]

As you can see, now we have one extra active thread that is in state of waiting. Probably the method `http.GetRequestStream()` spawns it. Everything is fine, but.. this thread keeps hanging like that for the whole app lifecycle, which seems not to be the intended behaviour.

Am I misusing `GetRequestStream` somehow?

Comment: Yes, I have also read that GetRequestStream works asynchronously and this explain the extra thread, but it doesn`t explain why does this thread continue to live after closing and disposing the stream. For me it seems that this thread is some kind of deadlocked or sth like that.

Comment: @rene, could you please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? I think it is a sufficient explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use [ilspy](http://ilspy.net/) it looks like the request is send asynchronously. That would explain the extra thread.

Looking a little bit deeper the `HttpWebRequest` creates a static `TimerQueue` with one thread and a never ending loop, that has a `Monitor.WaitAny` in it. Every webrequest in the appdomain will register a timer callback for timeout handling and all those callbacks are handled by that thread. Due to it being static that instance will never get garbage collected and therefore it will keep hold of the thread.

It did register for the `AppDomain.Unload` event so if that fires it will clean up it's resources including any threads.

Do notice that these are all internal classes and those implementation details might change at any time.